# Multicolor circle progress bar

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I am using [react-circular-progressbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-circular-progressbar) for creating the circular progress bar with one percentage value in react. Now I need to pass more then two percentage values.
Please advice me how can I achieve this or let me know if I can use another module or anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Recharts** library to achieve what you want. But you have to develop (not from the scratch) a bit customized component using **Recharts** provided components. This library is very flexible but it will be bit complex than what you using to right now.

http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/CustomActiveShapePieChart

I develop something similar to you asking,

```
let chartData = [{ value: parseInt(final_val), color: 'red' }, { value: ((parseInt(remain_val) > 0) ? parseInt(remain_val) : 0), color: 'grey' }]

<PieChart >
<Pie data={chartData} cx="50%" cy="85%" startAngle={180} endAngle={0} innerRadius='105%' outerRadius='140%' fill="red" label >
{
     chartData.map((entry, index) => <Cell key={index} fill={index === 1 ? '#ddd' : 'red'} />)
}
</Pie>
<text style={{ fontSize: '5vw', fontWeight: '800' }} x="50%" y="70%" dy={8} textAnchor="middle" fill="#000">{final_val}</text>
<g> <line x1="27%" y1="76%" x2="73%" y2="76%" style={{ stroke: 'rgb(255,0,0)', strokeWidth: '2' }} />
</g>
<text style={{ fontSize: '3vw', fontWeight: '600' }} x="50%" y="90%" dy={8} textAnchor="middle" fill="#8884d8">{target_val}</text>
</PieChart>
```

Above code create something like this

[image: Pie chart with progress]